# Subtract two columns and show outcome in the next line

Tags: python, pandas, subtraction, cumulative-sum

I would like to get a cumulative sum of X and also subtract X-Y in each column. The remainder should be found and added to the next row. I would also like the count to reset to 0 at the end of every month. For example, the 1st of every month should be a 0 in X.

For example:

DF1:

| Date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-25 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-04-26 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-27 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-28 | 56 | 53 |
| 2021-04-29 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-30 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-05-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-05-02 | 5 | 0 |
| 2021-05-03 | 5 | 5 |
| 2021-05-04 | 0 | 0 |

Dfdesired:

| Date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-25 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-04-26 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-27 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-28 | 56 | 53 |
| 2021-04-29 | 3 | 0 |
| 2021-04-30 | 4 | 0 |
| 2021-05-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-05-02 | 5 | 0 |
| 2021-05-03 | 10 | 5 |
| 2021-05-04 | 5 | 0 |

I have tried this for the cumulative sum but it does not seem to be working and I am unsure how to reset to 0 at the end of the month.

```
df1['X'] += df1['X'] - df1['Invoice Rejected']
```

Comment: What happens if first of the month has a non-zero value for x? Do you still want it to be overwritten by zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to apply the calculation on each month:

```
df["X"] = (df["X"] + 
           df.eval("Diff = X - Y").groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M"))["Diff"]
             .cumsum().shift().fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
        Date     X   Y
0 2021-04-25   4.0   4
1 2021-04-26   0.0   0
2 2021-04-27   0.0   0
3 2021-04-28  56.0  53
4 2021-04-29   3.0   0
5 2021-04-30   4.0   0
6 2021-05-01   4.0   0
7 2021-05-02   5.0   0
8 2021-05-03  10.0   5
9 2021-05-04   5.0   0
```

Details:

1. Create a "Diff" column temporary
2. Use pd.Grouper to group on "Date" with a freq="M" and cumsum
3. Shift and fillna
4. Add back to "X"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want:

```
df['X'] = df['X'] + (df['X'] - df['Y']).cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)
```

Which yields:

```
          Date     X   Y
0  2021-04-25    4.0   4
1  2021-04-26    0.0   0
2  2021-04-27    0.0   0
3  2021-04-28   56.0  53
4  2021-04-29    3.0   0
5  2021-04-30    4.0   0
6  2021-05-01    4.0   0
7  2021-05-02    9.0   0
8  2021-05-03   14.0   5
9  2021-05-04    9.0   0
```

Comment: Hi this answer is good but does not take into account how to reset X at the end of each month.

Comment: Gotcha, if you can provide an example of what you expect the data to look like after the second step I might understand better. Anyway, two-part questions are discouraged so perhaps open a new question for the second piece of the puzzle.

Comment: sorry for the late response. Essentially on the first of every month, X should reset to 0. For example, in the final dataset you created, 2021-05-01 X should be 0.

Comment: I have edited the final dataset to account for reset at the start of every month.

Comment: This is solution results in incorrect values for X on 2021/05/02, 2021/05/03 and 2021/05/04. The calcuation doesn't account for month change.